# getJSON working but invalid feedback (parseerror)

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am putting together a little intranet site for a smart home and would like to switch lights via a web page. There is a PC running which can interpret http requests like this one:

```
http://username:password@10.0.1.xx/cgi-bin/scada-remote/request.cgi?m=json&r=grp&fn=write&alias=1/1/20&value=true
```

This works like a charm and is written as per documentation of the hardware controlling (at least part of) the smart home bus. So far so good.

Now I would like to trigger this request out of JavaScript. As far as I understand after hours of searching and trying I need to use 'getJSON' because of the cross-site (was that the word?) nature of the request. I also needed to add 'callback=?' to the URL, otherwise it didn't work, i.e. the light would not switch. The function:

```
function testLight(lightState) {
 $.getJSON("http://username:password@10.0.1.xx/cgi-bin/scada-remote/request.cgi?m=json&r=grp&fn=write&alias=1/1/20&value=" + lightState + "&callback=?",
    function(response) {
        alert('hi');
    });
```

This function works, but strange enough the callback function does not trigger. I then rewrote the function to simple ajax:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://username:password@10.0.1.xx/cgi-bin/scada-remote/request.cgi?m=json&r=grp&fn=write&alias=1/1/70&value=" + lightState + "&callback=?',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result){
        alert("token recieved: " + result.token);
      },
      error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error: ' + textStatus);
      },
      complete: function(request, textStatus) { //for additional info
        alert('complete: ' + request.responseText);
        alert('complete: ' + textStatus);
      }
    });
```

I get "error: parseerror", "complete: undefined" and "complete: parseerror" as feedbacks out of the function above. But the light switches correctly.

Pasting the URL

```
http://username:password@10.0.1.xx/cgi-bin/scada-remote/request.cgi?m=json&r=grp&fn=write&alias=1/1/20&value=true
```

into the browser results in switching light and the word 'true' in the browser window. So feedback seems to arrive.

What am I doing wrong with the getJSON function that the callback function does not trigger, or more precise, I get 'parseerror' and 'undefined' feedbacks?

Many thanks and best regards

Comment: Does the api even support JSONP? If not, then the request will be sent, but the callback will never fire, because the server does not send an appropriate response including the padding (callback).

Comment: Probably the API does not, at least I could not find anything in the very short documentation. Do you see any other way of doing it? And why do I have to add "callback=?" to the URL to get it running in the first place?

Comment: Read about how JSONP works http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/

Comment: So it seems the reply needs to be different from the API if I understand correctly? There is no other way to get this to work apart from having the manufacturer append the API to be able to handle JSONP?